# Replacing [[wiki:Title]] with a link to my wiki

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a simple replacement of `[[wiki:Title]]` into `<a href="/wiki/Title">Title</a>`.

So far, I have:

```
$text = preg_replace("/\[\[wiki:(\w+)\]\]/","<a href=\"/wiki/read/\\1\">\\1</a>", $text);
```

The above works for single words, but I'm trying to include spaces and on occasion special characters.

I get the `\w+`, but `\w\s+` and/or `\.+` aren't doing anything.

Could someone improve my understanding of basic regex? And I don't mean for anyone to simply point me to a webpage.

Comment: If you truly want to improve your understanding of basic regex, a good place to start _is_ to read up on it. Since you've got the specific answer you were after to get you out of trouble this time, perhaps now you won't mind a suggestion of a useful site?  This is IMHO the best regex reference I've seen so far, that covers basics through to advanced useage. http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\w\s+` means "a word-character, followed by 1 or more spaces". You probably meant `(\w|\s)+` ("1 or more of a word character or a space character").

`\.+` means "one or more dots". You probably meant `.+` (1 or more of any character - except newlines, unless in single-line mode).

The more robust way is to use

```
\[wiki:(.+?)\]
```

This means "1 or more of any character, but stop at first position where the rest matches", i.e. stop at first right bracket in this case. Without ? it would look for the longest available match - i.e. past the first bracket.

Comment: I suppose what tripped me was the order of the \ and ?. I kept trying to put ?\w to find multiple words. Thanks, the .+? works.

Comment: +1. @Bryan note that \s doesn't just match a literal space, it matches "white space", meaning literal space _and tab_. It will also match platform independent newline (eg whatever combination of LF and/or CR represents \n), unless using multi-line matching mode where \n won't be matched.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `\[\[wiki:([\w\s]+)\]\]`. Notice square brackets around `\w\s`.

If you are learning regular expressions, you will find this site useful for testing: http://rexv.org/

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely getting there, but you've got a couple syntax errors.

When you're using multiple character classes like \w and \s, in order to match within that group, you have to put them in [square brackets] like so... ([\w\s]+) this basically means one or more of words or white space.

Putting a backslash in front of the period escapes it, meaning the regex is searching for a period.

As for matching special characters, that's more of a pain. I tried to come up with something quickly, but hopefully someone else can help you with that.
(Great cheat sheet here, I keep a copy on my desk at all times: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/ )

Comment: I like zeuxcg's answer for any characters :) although I'd use my example over his for the words and spaces.

Comment: No joke, I just found this cheatsheet. It's up on my computer now. Thanks.