# Mysql query based on string within a preg_match or preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557792/regex-q-replacing-wikititle-with-a-link-to-my-wiki), I managed to get some text replacement working for my wiki. Which works great with titles. But now I'd like to replace titles with IDs. For my wiki, I simply replace [[wiki::Title]] with a link to that title. How can I get links from IDs in that title spot?

The below code works, but only outputs the ID. Example text includes `[[tdh::1]]` and `[[tdh::5]]`. I would now like to take that ID and query my database for it and use that result to build a link.

```
$text = preg_replace("/\[\[tdh::(.+?)\]\]/","<a href=\"*page here*?task=tdhelp&action=read&id=\\1\">\\1</a>", $text);
```

Pointing me in the right direction would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and for the `callback` parameter use a function that uses the ID to fetch the name from the database.

Note that above approach, while simple, could potentially result in a lot of database calls. An improvement is to first find all the IDs using [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and store them in an array. Then you can fetch all the names in a single database call. The SQL you need will be something like this:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM links
WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?)
```

Watch out for SQL injection vulnerabilities if you aren't using parameterized queries. Store the results in an associative array with the ID as the key and the name as the value.

Finally you can use `preg_replace_callback` where the callback function finds the name from the array.

Comment: Upvoted since you have more pointers to the actual methods to use :).

Comment: Working on this now, be back with some results shortly.

Comment: Okay, I have something working... `function getTdhTitle { return id and title from query }` is located on my functions page. And then `$text = preg_replace_callback("/\[\[tdh::(.+?)\]\]/","getTdhTitle",$text);` is located on the page I wish to display. Working for me, but...

Comment: But what do you mean by too many database calls? Do you mean queries per match? At this time, I am only using this on my admin panel, and expect no more than 10 matches. This will increase in the future, but not any time soon. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Bryan: The first approach will result in a database call for each time the callback is called. Which is every time a match is found in the text. So if you have ten matches it will make ten database calls. The second approach will make at most one call.

Answer (score 1):

You should first read the id and any other association necessary from the database and cache them in some sort of array.

The you use a `preg_replace_callback` to to the actual replacement based on that cached data.

Alternatively you could to a two step process: try once and record the id's found (not replacement). Use those to query the db for additional data. Do another search and replace the results.

You could also do what @Mark suggested but if the page you are editing has 15 title you will make 15 queries to the db and that might work or not for you. In some high load it will probably not work. This means slow pages usually.

Comment: I knew someone else was going to suggest the same thing as me! Anyway +1 because your answer is right and you came up with the same solution independently from me.